# Data is returning null, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Here is the code I am using to get Facebook friend list, the class

```
public class FBUser
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    // empty constructor
    public FBUser()
    { }
}
```

the list class

```
public class FbFriendList
{
    public WcdyList<FBUser> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the method I am using to get the friend list:

```
try
{   
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
        FbFriendList myfriends = client.Get<FbFriendList>("me/friends?fields=id,name,username,picture,link");

        if (myfriends.Data.Count > 0) return myfriends.Data;
        else return null;
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

myfriends is returning the data object null, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to get this information using same `access_token` with [OpenGraph Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

Comment: @JuicyScripter yup I checked using open graph explorer and I am getting the result back but the problem here is the Get method, because I am not getting any documentation about all the methods of SDK, it has a method `public T Get<T>(string path)` which I am trying to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like this to get the friends info

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
dynamic result = app.Get("me/friends?fields=id,name,username,picture,link");
```

Now you can map the resulting data to your custom classes...

**Update:**
Seems like you using `Data` instead of `data` (you should stick to original names of fields in response)

```
public class FbFriendList {
  public WcdyList<FBUser> data { get; set; }
}
```

**Update2:**
You can loop over the list to get friends details like this:

```
foreach (dynamic friend in result.data) {
  string friendId = friend.id;
  string friendName = friend.name;
  // etc...
}
```

Or like this if you not yet on [.net4](/questions/tagged/.net4):

```
var resultData = (IList<object>)result.data;
foreach (var friendObj in resultData) {
  var friend = (IDictionary<string, object>)friendObj;
  string friendId = friend["id"];
  string friendName = friend["name"];
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: I think dynamic is only available in .Net 4.0 and I am using .Net 3.5

Comment: You are correct. For `.Net` bellow version 4.0 you may use dictionary `var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)app.Get("me/friends?fields=id,name,username,picture,link")`

Comment: I know I can use like this but I am asking why it's not returning the desired result when I am trying to use this 'public T Get<T>(string path)' and please also tell me how you read the friend list after your result variable is populated.